# Weblogic cannot lookup EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/myPackage.ServiceImpl/eventQuery in /app/ejb/my-dao-2016.jar/#MyDaoImpl.; remaining name 'comp/env/myPackage/ServiceImpl/eventQuery'

I'm working on Weblogic 12.2.1 now, and I get this error (and others like that, for every EJB in the application). EJBs are visible when I go into deployment summary, point is that they are under `my-ear` not `my-dao`, I have no idea why weblogic is looking there, `my-dao` has nothing to do with `eventQuery`. I tried to specifying a name/mappedName/lookup in the annotations, nothing works. I think that if I somehow manage to tell it to look in `/app/ejb/my-ear.jar`, not in `/app/ejb/my-dao-2016.jar` then everything will be fine, but I have no idea where to do that. Here's some code, but it's all pretty straightforward, I have no `ejb.xml` or anything like that, just annotations.

Oh, and probably the most important thing, everything works perfectly on Weblogic 12.1.3.

```java
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @EJB
    private EventQuery eventQuery;
    ...
}
@Stateless
@Local(EventQuery.class)
public class EventQueryImpl implements EventQuery {
 ...
}
public interface EventQuery {
 ...
}
```

Comment: If I remember well, when you deploy an app (.jar, .ear...), it goes under the admin server by default. You can specify at deployment time or later after it has been deployed to be available under a specific target. My guess is that you have probably deployed to the wrong target.

Comment: When you looked in the JNDI tree which code you use?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by a bug/change in Weblogic: BUG:22988141 - DEPENDENCY INJECTION IS FAILED WHEN DEPLOYING APPLICATION

The differences of behavior between 12.2.1 and 12.1.3 comes from differences of CDI support version:
WLS 12.1.3 supports CDI 1.0
WLS 12.2.1 supports CDI 1.1

There are 2 solutions:

Add beans.xml like follows into application to find MDB.

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
bean-discovery-mode="all"
version="1.1">
```

beans-discovery-mode="all" (default "annotated") or
modify configuration

```
<domain>
...
<cdi-container>
.
<implicit-bean-discovery-enabled>false</implicit-bean-discovery-enabled>
.
</cdi-container>
...
</domain>
```

The modification can be done via the console. Then WLS 12.2.1 disables CDI.